# my code as follows

Tags: struts2

**struts.xml**;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts  
        Configuration 2.1//EN" "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.1.dtd">
<struts>  
    <constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="false" />
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
    <package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="struct1" class="p.Product">
            <result>/index.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>  
</struts>
```

**index.jsp**

```
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>  
<s:form action="struts" >  
    <s:textfield name="id" label="Product Id"></s:textfield>  
    <s:textfield name="name" label="Product Name"></s:textfield>  
    <s:textfield name="price" label="Product Price"></s:textfield>  
    <s:submit value="save"></s:submit>  
</s:form>
```

**product.java**

```
package p;

public class Product {
    private int id;  
    private String name;  
    private int price;  

    public int getId() {  
        return id;  
    }  

    public void setId(int id) {  
        this.id = id;  
    }  

    public String getName() {  
        return name;  
    }  

    public void setName(String name) {  
        this.name = name;  
    }  

    public int getPrice() {  
        return price;  
    }  

    public void setPrice(int price) {  
        this.price = price;  
    }  

    public String execute(){  
        return "success";  
    }  
}
```

**welcome.jsp**

```
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>  

Product Id:<s:property value="id"/><br/>  
Product Name:<s:property value="name"/><br/>  
Product Price:<s:property value="price"/><br/>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
        <display-name>struts1</display-name>
        <welcome-file-list>
            <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
            <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
            <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
            <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
            <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
            <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
        </welcome-file-list>

        <filter>
            <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
            <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>
        </filter>
        <filter-mapping>  
            <filter-name>struts1</filter-name>  
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>  
        </filter-mapping>  
    </web-app>
```

This is my code. Can anyone tell me what's wrong in the code. It shows the error `The request resource is not available`.
The index page gets displayed when i tried to enter the values i couldn't get the value in the next page.

Comment: if you follow the link that should work? share your code ?

Comment: Error: this is not how StackOverflow works.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this in `struts.xml`

```
<package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
```

Comment: thanks .i tried this possibilities already even i got the same error "Struts has detected an unhandled exception: "

Comment: i m new to stackflow so i dont knw were to add my code

Comment: i send my code .tel me whats wrong in my code.As i was new to struts

Comment: change action name struts1 to struts in struts.xml

Comment: thanks...but i couldnt run my program.when i run my struts,hibernate program my server (Apache) fails to run ..i was my major problem.